# Dyntopo: Re-symmetrize only part of mesh

Tags: sculpting

I've sculpted a mesh using Dyntopo with symmetry enabled. I've then disabled symmetry to make the front half of my creature non-symmetric (think a cat with one paw raised). Then I've turned symmetry back on to work on the back half of the sculpt.

Using Dyntopo has left some non-symmetric artifacts on one side of the back half (the bit that should be symmetric). Is there a way to restore symmetry but only to the back half of the mesh?

I've tried using the mask in sculpting, but the whole mesh is affected by the Dyntopo symmetrize button.

Using the symmetrize function in edit mode only works on selected vertices but leaves holes in the mesh along the selection area. I'll fill these and go back to sculpting but I wondered if there was another way.

A tool that applies the symmetrize function to part of a mesh would have to ease the vertices around the edge of the mask but sculpting already does stuff this clever.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to do all your mirrored sculpting first,
then turn mirror off, and finalize asymmetrical details.

For instance:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLb_CCoWn5o

If you've already started sculpting without symmetry,
it's possible to copy your sculpture, then place a cube around the area.

Use *boolean modifier* set to **intersect** on one sculpt & cube,
Use *boolean modifier* set to **difference** on the other sculpt & cube.

Continue sculpting on the area that only has symmetrical details.

Merge the two halves with a boolean *union* once you're finished,
and smooth any seam with the sculpt tools.

Comment: I tried using booleans to separate, and then rejoin the mesh, but because of the flat faces added at the split the join after the union was ugly and hard to smooth. Doing the symmetrize in edit mode, then filling (ALT-F) the small gap produced a better mesh. Next time I'll leave the asymmetry to last.

Comment: I know how you feel.  I ran into the same thing the first time I was using it, too.